# What is the optimal speed which minimizes the overall cost?

Tags: calculus, optimization

The cost of fuel for a car is proportional to the square of the car's speed. If you drive the car at 25 mph, the cost is $25.

The other costs which are independent of speed amounts to $100. What is the optimal speed which minimizes the cost?

Comment: If the only thing you can optimize is the speed, and the only cost associated with the speed  is proportional to the square of the speed, then the optimal strategy is to drive at $0$mph. Just don't drive and there won't be any other costs. Is there other information that is missing from this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure! I actually messaged my professor because I'm pretty sure we're missing the total distance traveled. I don't understand how we can measure cost efficiency if we don't have that value on hand.

Comment: Perhaps there is another factor. For example, you have to travel ten miles and every hour you drive costs $\$50$ or something like that.

Comment: He just said to try to write the cost as a function of the speed...? I'm VERY confused :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the speed at which the motorist will make the cost per mile a minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336268)

Comment: The question should ask you to minimise *cost per mile* or (as you guessed) the cost of driving *a specified distance*. The *other costs* should be *per hour* of running the vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

With the given information we know

$$\text{Cost from speed}(v)=av^2$$

for some constant $a$. We also know

$$25=\text{Cost from speed}(25)=a25^2$$

$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{25}$$

This implies

$$\text{Total Cost}(v)=100+\text{Cost from speed}(v)=100+\frac{v^2}{25}$$

This is minimized for $v=0$.

Comment: Oh my gosh this actually makes sense. Thank you!